# Least number of numbers to guarantee two sum to $101$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I'm struggling currently with one of my problems in my homework. The professor gave two hints to the following problem.

> Problem: Find the least amount of different numbers to pick from positive integers that are at most $100$ to guarantee two pairs of numbers that add up to $101$.

Hints:

- Show that $n$ is sufficient to guarantee
- Show that $n-1$ is not sufficient

Although I understand the basic logic of the pigeon hole principle, I would greatly appreciate it if in the answer, the definition of the pigeon hole is expanded upon.

Comment: Welcome to mse! I've edited your question to use mathjax, as well as to have a more descriptive title. Both of these are helpful for maintaining the usability of the site, and in the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Each positive integer less than $100$ is like a sock, with a unique mate (e.g. the only number that can pair with $57$ is $44$). Think about it in smaller terms. If you had, say, $3$ pairs of socks (i.e. $6$ socks in total), how many could you draw out without drawing a single pair? How many could you draw out before you got $2$ pairs? It might be easier to think in smaller numbers.

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better

Comment: It is not clear to me how the pigeon hole principle applies. Think in term of what pairs are needed.

Comment: Had the question been about *three* pairs, there would be no doubt, but with two pairs, my doubt is whether you actually mean two pairs or **a** pair.

Comment: Particularly as the header reads "Least number of numbers to guarantee two sum to $101$"

Answer (score 1):

Number $100$ cards, and place them into two columns of $50$ rows each, such that each row sums to $101$.

Now it is obvious that you can only take at most one card from each row and not take two that sum to $101$. This gives you $50$ cards. After that, every card gives a pair, so $52$ cards guarantees two pairs.

$51$ cards isn't sufficient, for example you could pick $1-51$.